# Морфемный состав слова «благословляя»

Tags: морфемика, морфемный-разбор, деепричастия, суффиксы, корень-слова

Каков морфемный состав слова *благословляя*?

И *л* — это суффикс или часть корня?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*л* — это точно не суффикс, потому что у суффикса должно быть значение, которого у *л* в *благословляя* совершенно нет.

Разумнее всего считать это вариантом корня *слов* (сравните: *слово*), который используется в определенных условиях.

Таким образом, деление на морфемы:
благ- — корень, словл- — корень, -я — суффикс.

В слове также есть соединительный гласный -о- и гласный основы -я- (благословл**я**я). (Они не являются морфемами, потому что не имеют никакого значения. В школе, однако, стоит отмечать их как суффиксы.)

Comment: Основой является все слово?

Comment: @Flexfor всё, кроме -я на конце.

Comment: Почему тогда во всех школьных разборах и последний суффикс входит в основу? Это является ошибкой?

Comment: @Flexfor если в вашем учебнике он входит в основу... наверно, разумно ради хорошей отметки подчиниться этому решению. Оно, однако, неверно, даже если взять школьное определение основы: часть слова без окончания и формообразующих суффиксов. Деепричастие — форма глагола, соответственно, она образуется с помощью __формообразующего__ суффикса и не входит в основу.